# How to manage config changes through interface and into version control efficiently

Tags: magento2.3, configuration, interface, bin-magento

When manipulating config in the interface and wanting to track it into version control, as I see it, there are multiple options and I have doubts with every single one of them.

1. `bin/magento app:config:dump`, exports literally everything and will lock every single config field in the interface. Which I think is really inconvenient, since you will be forced to delete a value from the config to re-enable it in the interface to be able to change it again. Or you'll have to edit it manually in `config.php`.
2. `bin/magento app:config:dump <config-types...>` which exports all config within that config-type, eg. `theme`. How do I know which config type to export when I change a value within the interface?
3. `bin/magento config:set --lock-config <path> <value>` which sets a config value and simultaneously writes it to the shared config. To use this, is there any way to easily know which `<path>` I need to use when I just changed the value through the interface?

How do I - as a developer - edit some arbitrary config value through the admin interface, export it as quickly as possible, without preventing myself from ever (easily) editing other config values through the interface? Or, how would I go about finding out the config-type or config path for a value I just changed so I can quickly export?